# CSS - make text decoration: underline extend all the way to :before elements

Tags: html, css

I'm using an [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) icon font to add an icon on the `:before` element of an `<a>`. It works great but the `text-decoration: underline` only covers the icon, and then the text in the anchor. There is a blank, not underlined section between the two.

How can I make the underline extend across both the `<a>` tag and its pseudo elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `text-decoration: underline` you could work around that by giving to the anchor a couple of properties like `display: inline-block` plus a `width` and finally a `border-bottom`. Just a thought

Comment: This would have worked but I had a number of nested elements throwing `text-decoration: underline`. I eventually had to track every one of them down and just remove it entirely.